# Point users to a specific url directory for some posts

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks

I use my WP website to teach a course, and I want to tell my students to go to "mycourse.com/syllbus" to get posts related to the syllabus.  WP is installed in mycourse.com.

Is there a way within WP to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you organize your posts into categories, WP will automatically make all posts in the category 'syllabus' available under 'mycourse.com\category\syllabus'. If this is not enough you can install a plugin like [No Category Base](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/) that will reduce that url to 'mycourse.com\syllabus'.